# g++ fatal error when compiling Google Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile, compiler-errors, googletest

I am trying to compile some tests with Google Test. I am using the sample makefile that comes with GTEST, but from a different directory. I added some make targets to compile my tests and sources, but left the Google Test bits untouched, however compiling the Google Test Sources fails with this notification:

```
    g++ -isystem ~/stm32/googletest/googletest/include -I~/stm32/googletest/googletest -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -c \
            ~/stm32/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc
/home/nuclear_kiwi/stm32/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:42:24: Fatal Error: src/gtest.cc: File or directory not found
     #include "src/gtest.cc"
```

Why does this fail, even though the source path is supplied in the call to the compiler?

Comment: this file is not found, src/gtest.cc. Have you checked this file existence in your directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
-I~/stm32/googletest/googletest
```

to:

```
-I ~/stm32/googletest/googletest
```

Bash only recognizes the tilde-prefix operator when the `~` occurs at the
beginning of a word. [3.4.3. Tilde expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)

Comment: @nuclear_kiwi Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)